# Blazor data post with file to .net core API

Tags: asp.net-core, post, file-upload, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm deploying blazor ser-side application. when I post only data via API, it's work fine. but i want to post data and file both throw a API. And i use  **BlazorInputFile** -v 0.1.0-preview-00002 library.
when i get my data object from controller by using **HttpContext.Request.Form**, it's return string value instead of byte[].
    My blazor component.razor file

```
private async Task Save()
{
    try
    {
        model.Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataList);
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        await file.Data.CopyToAsync(ms);

        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent {
            { new ByteArrayContent(ms.GetBuffer()), "image", file.Name },
            { new ByteArrayContent(SerializeToByteArray(model)), "data" }
        };

        await httpClient.PostAsync("api/controllar/method", content);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

```
and controller method :
```

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public ApiResponse Create2()
{
    try
    {
        var byteData = HttpContext.Request.Form["data"];
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return null;
}
```